# Footable paging limit does not work in some cases

Tags: asp.net, responsive, footable

Here http://ctd1.aju.edu/foo.html it works.

```
paging: {
             enabled: true,
             limit:2,
             size: 5
          },
          state: {
             enabled: true
          },
          "data-breakpoints": {
             "xs": 480,
             "sm": 768,
             "md": 992,
             "lg": 1200,
             "xl": 1400
          }
```

But here it does not http://ctd1.aju.edu/foo.aspx

```
      paging: {

         "limit": 2,
        "size":10

      },
      state: {
         enabled: true
      },
      "data-breakpoints": {
         "xs": 480,
         "sm": 768,
         "md": 992,
         "lg": 1200,
         "xl": 1400
      }
```

The second is getting data from a database. The size attribute works OK but the limit not. I tried it with large data set I got tens of paging links.
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include footable.paging.css for it to work properly. It seems like you are only adding footable.core.standalone.css, which is not enough.